# recyclerview must not be null

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

```
Process: com.bignerdranch.android.on_callbabysitting, PID: 19624
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bignerdranch.android.on_callbabysitting/com.bignerdranch.android.on_callbabysitting.Home}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: recyclerv_view must not be null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: recyclerv_view must not be null
        at com.bignerdranch.android.on_callbabysitting.Home.onCreate(Home.kt:42)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerv_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height ="match_parent">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>

package com.bignerdranch.android.on_callbabysitting

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.View.inflate
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.recycv1.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.sidebar.*
import java.lang.IllegalStateException

class Home : AppCompatActivity() {


    var names = ArrayList<String>()
    var imgUrls = ArrayList<String>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.homepage)
        lateinit var context: Context

        var helper = MyDBHelper(applicationContext)
        var db = helper.readableDatabase
        var rs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM USERS", null)

        rs.moveToFirst()
        while(rs.isAfterLast == false)
        {
            names.add(rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("EMAIL")))
            rs.moveToNext()
            names.add(rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("FIRST_NAME")))
            rs.moveToNext()
            //names.add(rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("LAST_NAME")))
            //rs.moveToNext()
        }
        recyclerv_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerv_view.adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(imgUrls, names, this)
        /*names.add(editTextTextEmailAddress3.getText().toString())
        names.add(editTextTextPassword.getText().toString())
        //names.add(editTextTextEmailAddress3.getText().toString())
        //names.add(editTextTextPassword.getText().toString())*/

        //try {
           // recyclerv_view.adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter.First(this, imgUrls, names)
            //recyclerv_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
       // }catch (ignored: IllegalStateException)
        //{

        //}
        //val recyclerView : RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerv_view)
        //val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerv_view)
        //recyclerView.setAdapter(first)
        //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(this))
    }


}



package com.bignerdranch.android.on_callbabysitting

import android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import java.security.AccessController.getContext

open class RecyclerViewAdapter(val imgNames: ArrayList<String>, val imgPic: ArrayList<String>, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    //var Context = context

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {

       // lateinit var cimg:CircleImageView
        //lateinit var img:TextView

        //lateinit var parentLayout: LinearLayout

        val CircleImageView = itemView.findViewById<CircleImageView>(R.id.profile_image)
        val TextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView19)
        val TextView1 = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView18)
        val TextView2 = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView20)
        val parentLayout = itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.parent_layout)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        //var View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.homepage, parent, false)
        //var viewHolder = ViewHolder(View)
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.homepage, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return imgNames.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {


       /* Glide
            .with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(imgPic.get(position))
            .into(holder.CircleImageView)

        var First = First(context,imgNames, imgPic)
        First.imgN.add(imgNames.get(position))

        */
        holder?.TextView?.text = imgNames.get(position)
        holder?.TextView1.text = imgNames.get(position)
        holder?.TextView2.text = imgNames.get(position)
        holder?.parentLayout.parent
    }
}
```

I am trying to have my code display the user's name at login in the home page, I can successfully move in from one activity to the next with a click, but when I add the recycler view in my home activity, it doesn't work. Attached is the recycler view XML, adapter activity, and my home class activity along with the log.

Answer (score 0):

In your imports there are multiple UI's imported. Just check once where the recyclerview lies actually.

```
 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.recycv1.*
 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.sidebar.*
```

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean. Could you pls be more explicit?

Comment: in which xml recyclerview is ?

Comment: Recycv1 is the xml

Answer (score 0):

you've not initialized the recyclerv_view in the activity class.

Comment: Thank you. So I have to initialize in the activity main? By using findbyid?

Comment: no need of findviewbyid as you are using kotlin